# Add node using OpsCenter on EC2 with EC2Snitch fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I was trying to add an additional node on EC2 using OpsCenter.
The existing node uses Ec2Snitch, so I chose the same snitch for the new node.

However, OpsCenter fails with:

Error provisioning cluster: A topology_map argument of the form {ip: [dc, rack]} is required for the selected endpoint snitch (org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch)

Please advice.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

what version of opscenter and DSE are you using?

you can add it with another snitch (dsedelegate) and after it provision, change it to ec2snitch, works just fine

Comment: Yes, this is how I end up doing that: using another snitch and changing once completed.